# How do I create a trigger that cascades new rows into another table?

Tags: mysql-5.5

I am having a table name `link` with two columns `link1` and `link2` and another table name `hide` with four columns `hide1, link1,link2` and `hide2`. If i insert data into link table the data should insert into hide table in the column link1 and link2..

How can i write  a query for this?

Here my query its not executing:

```
CREATE TRIGGER linkTRIGGER
    AFTER INSERT ON link
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
       INSERT INTO Hide(link1,link2) VALUES(OLD.link1,OLD.link2)
```

Comment: What should go to the other 2 columns of `Hide`? Can you add sample data?

Answer (score 2):

First, `Hide` has 4 columns and you provide values for only 2 of them. What should go to the other 2?

Second as the [Trigger syntax in MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) states:

> In an `INSERT` trigger, only `NEW.col_name` can be used; **there is no old row.**

So, you can use `NEW.link1, NEW.link2` but not `OLD.link1, OLD.link2` and this would be valid:

```
CREATE TRIGGER linkTRIGGER
    AFTER INSERT ON link
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
       INSERT INTO Hide (link1, link2, hide1, hide2) 
       VALUES (NEW.link1, NEW.link2, NEW.link1, NEW.link2) ;
```

but no idea if that's what you want. Depends what values you want to pass to the two `hide` columns.